# Validation default value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check if all items of a list meet a set of criteria:

```
bool AreValid(list<string> vals)
{
   bool allValid=true;

   foreach(string val in vals)
   {
       if(!condition1)
          ...
          allValid=false;
       else if(!condition2)
          ...
          allValid=false;
   }

   return allValid;

}
```

The reason I can't use LINQ `All()` is that for each failed condition I'm doing some job.

is it safe to set `allValid` as `true` by default?

Comment: Why don't you just return false if any of the conditions fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is fine - I mean it definitelly works and there is nothing unsafe in assigning default value of `True` to `allValid`.

My concern is the design. The name of your method `AreValid` suggest that it is just checking if objects meet specific criteria. You've mentioned that for all those objects that do not meet the criteria there is something being done on them. That doesn't seem to be the very greatest approach.
I would suggest you consider separating checking if objects meets condition and changing state of the objects. It will make your code simpler and easier to read and understand to others. Is changing object state really what you expect from the method named `AreValid`? It would be quite a surprise for me if I found similar method in the code base.

The other thing is that you could use LiNQ and check for all the objects that do not meet the criteria and then perform some actions on those objects.

Comment: I am glad you found it helpful. As for the separation - take a look at CQRS (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)

Answer (score 3):

It's safe. A few things to consider:

1. When the list is empty you might want to return `false`.
2. Consider using an abstract data type (instead of string) which stores your data (the string) and move the validation logic to there.
3. As *Jeff Vanzella* already suggested, you can return `false` immediately when you now that a value is not valid. It's faster and easier to read:

   ```
   bool AreValid(list<string> vals)
   {
      foreach(string val in vals)
      {
          if(!condition1)
             ...
             return false;
          if(!condition2)
             ...
             return false;
      }

      return true;

   }
   ```

   Note that you don't need the `else` keyword anymore.